# Razor Pages .Net Core - Calling C# method from Javascript / AJax

Tags: c#, ajax, razor-pages

I have looked at a good few examples online of how to contact a .Net Core C# method from an Ajax call in Razor Pages - however having gone through a bunch of examples I can't seem to figure out why I can't get it to work for my scenario... Which I dont think is anything special!

I have a button to call this method on click:

[image]

and that `DeleteSeasonTrip()` method looks like this:

[image]

Now, I have the following method setup:

[image]

Which lives in the class **EditModel**:

[image]

in the following structure:

[image]

If I try to call the ajax request I get the follwoing:

[image]

Am I missing a crucial piece of the puzzle here? I feel I have followed the examples I have seen close enuogh, however I am really quite new to Razor Pages for Core so think I am just missing something simple!?

Comment: You are missing the Request Verification Token in your AJAX POST: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

Comment: Ahhhh I thought I had tried this but have now gone through the link and all makes sense. All working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Brind comment on the original question, I have gone through this page and applied the Request Verification Token and now all works a treat:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

[image]

With this RVT in place I am now able to hit the method in code behind and the request completes successfully.